# Different ways to approach $\infty$

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

I was reading up on the definition of an integral and in 'Mathematical methods for Physics and Engineering' by K. F. Riley, M. P. Hobson & S. J. Bence came across this sentence:

> If now $n$ is allowed to tend to infinity in any way whatsoever, subject only to the constraint that the length of every subinterval $\zeta_{i-1}$ to $\zeta_i$ tends to zero, then S might, or might not, tend to a unique limit, I. If it does then the definite integral of $f(x)$ between $a$ and $b$ is defined as having the value $I$.

Firstly is this basically saying that $I$ is the definite integral iff the limit as $n\rightarrow \infty$ exists?

And what other ways are there to tend to $\infty$ apart from going to there from below (as you cannot approach from higher values)>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this means that $I$ is the definite integral iff the limit exists.

What is meant by that $n$ is allowed to go to $\infty$ in any way is that the partition $\{[\zeta_i, \zeta_{i+1}]\}$ may change in any way when $n$ increase as long as $|\zeta_i - \zeta_{i+1}| \to 0$.